# Execute commands on a server running under a system account

Tags: server, games, users

I setup a minecraft server on a Ubuntu system. When I launch the server from the command line, the server listens to the standard input and responds to various commands (such as changing the game mode, difficulty level or time of day):

> [image]

(See [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnFi72Gs2-o#t=120) of entering commands into the server console)

I don't like locking up my root user to run minecraft, though, so today I setup a system user named, simply, "minecraft":

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home --home /srv/minecraft-server minecraft
sudo addgroup --system minecraft
sudo adduser minecraft minecraft # this adds user "minecraft" the group "minecraft"
```

and I'm using a config file to launch the minecraft server under that user:

```
start on runlevel [2345]

console log
chdir /minecraft_server
setuid minecraft
setgid minecraft

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

exec /usr/bin/java -Xms1024M -Xmx1800M -jar minecraft_server.1.8.jar nogui
```

I want to send commands to the minecraft server via the standard input, just as I'm able to when I launch it under the current user. I've tried `su` and `sudo`, but the first seems to be ignored and the second produces a "command not found" error. Since minecraft is a system user, I'm guessing that interactive login is disabled.

> [image]

I've worked with linux systems a little in the past, but I'm out of my depth here. How can I pass along commands to the minecraft user to pass along to the minecraft server? Or is that not possible in my current situation?

Comment: First 13.10 is beyond EOL and not supported. Second, can you describe what you are trying to do? Normally you would send commands directly to the server as root , for example `sudo service apache2 start|stop|reload` no need to su to www-data

Comment: As an addition, what you are trying to do is create an `upstart` script to automatically start the server under the user and group `minecraft` once you do that you should be use minecraft-client to login using 192.168.0.XXX:25565

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - I hope I've clarified things a bit.

Comment: We understand you have a user, minecraft. what command are you trying to run ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands. I don't want to have to login to minecraft from the game client to issue commands to the server. (For example, I can SSH into the server from my Android phone. I'd like to be able to set the time or whitelist a user from via SSH.)

Comment: Linking to a wiki page does not really help me as I am not an expert on minecraft nor does it explain what command you are trying to run or how. try sudo `sudo -u minecraft foo`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - You asked which commands I was trying to invoke. That page contains a list of all the possible commands and a brief description of the minecraft multiplayer server console. I've added a couple screen grabs to the question. Perhaps that will help clarify what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That appears to be entering commands directly into the server console. I think you are best off running in screen. minecraft should be running as the minecraft user even though you started it as root, same as any other server `sudo service apache2 start` runs apache as www-data for example. When you ssh in re-attach to the screen session. You can try `sudo -u minecraft /bin/bash` and start the server there, but you still need to detach, so seems screen will solve your problem.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - Thanks... screen seems to have solved the problem for me. I had to del the minecraft user and recreate as a normal user (so that I could log in under that id). Started the server from the command line using a screen and then detached the screen. Seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

bodhi.zazen mentioned possibly "*[running in screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525374/execute-commands-on-a-server-running-under-a-system-account#comment716013_525374)*". I'd not heard of [screen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) before, but it seems to have solved the problem.

First, I had to delete the minecraft user and re-create it as a normal user. Then I gave the minecraft user the necessary permissions to the minecraft server folder (using chmod). After I successfully started the minecraft server from the new minecraft user account, I stopped it and started a screen session:

> [image]

and then started the minecraft server back up again (within screen):

> [image]

I then used the standard screen shortcut to detach from the screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> then just <kbd>d</kbd>). The minecraft server continues to run in the backround:

> [image]

I can easily reattach to issue commands using `screen -r`:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I can end my SSH session without shutting down the server, then log back in from a different machine. For example, here I am logging back in using an android phone and JuiceSSH:

> [image]

(noitce that you can see the commands I previously issued, since the screen was never terminated)